# Affect Instance Position of particles with another mesh (that is being instanced along a curve) using Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, procedural, instances, loop

I want to set up this scene so that the solid sphere is looping along the curve, while also affecting/displacing the offset position of the small particles (that are instanced).

This is what I have so far... I have the particle displacement working from moving the solid sphere around the scene
[image]
(figure 1.0)

However, when I animate the solid sphere along the curve, the displacement of the small particles no longer works. Perhaps it's because the Origin Point of the solid sphere is overridden by the curve's Origin Point?

[image]
(figure 2.0)

I'm very much a noob with Geometry Nodes and Blender in general... this website has been a huge help to me thus far in creating this. But I am stuck at this point.

I hope I'm making sense with what I'm trying to do. Open to ideas/ suggestions. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: The file contains a linked node group from an addon. Please make the node group local so we can use it (click the chain icon on the group node).

You are probably correct that the animated sphere location is just the static center of the curve. Instead of realizing the animated sphere geometry you could leave it as an instance, then pick the first instance's location from the geometry instead of the object location. That should give you the sphere animation again.

Comment: @lukas_t thanks very much for your reply! I have done my best to make the node groups local and have updated the blender file attached to the question. I hope it works now. Yes I think you're right about picking location from first instance, I will look at how to do this. Thanks so much, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @lukas_t I can confirm that your answer solved my problem. Thank you so much